# setting L_PREFER_CANVAS = true for a particular div

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

how can we set L_PREFER_CANVAS = true for a particular div ?
If I set `window.L_PREFER_CANVAS = true;` the complete window is been affected.
I tried

```
var obj = $('#divid');
obj.L_PREFER_CANVAS = true;
```

This is not working.So which is the correct method ?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to apply that preference to anything but the window. Looking at the source code, it is used in two places like so:

`L.Path.SVG && !window.L_PREFER_CANVAS`

So, setting `L_PREFER_CANVAS` on the div won't do anything because leaflet never checks for that property on anything but the window.